# How to Perfectly Center in IE8/CSS2.1?

Tags: css

Obviously for Chrome, Firefox, and Safari (which use CSS 3) you would do

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

But how can I perfectly center in IE8?

Comment: You need to add a fixed width in %, em or px.

Answer (score 3):

This code already works in IE8, IE7 and IE6, and people have been using them to center things for a good long while now. Have you tried your code before assuming that the `margin` properties are new to CSS3 (when in actual fact they have been around [since CSS**1**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#box-properties)) or that just because something is part of CSS3 automatically means IE8 and older won't recognize it?

If that code doesn't work for you in IE, your page is probably being displayed in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).